# sigaction argument ucontext_t

Tags: linux, signals

I set the `SA_SIGINFO` flags to handle the signal.When I use gdb to check the argument.I found `info` point to `0x7fffffffd2b0` and `context` point to `0x7fffffffd180`. I kown the true type of argument `context` is `ucontext_t`.Strangely, the space `0x7fffffffd2b0 - 0x7fffffffd180 == 0x130` is much less then `sizeof(ucontext_t) == 0x3c8`.So the memory which argument `context` points to can not be a complete  `ucontext_t` structure. Why this happened? Am I miss something?

```
void recvSignal(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    int a = 0x12345678;
    printf("received signal %d %d!\n", sig, a);
}
```